# How to properly implement and understand Theodorsen's function?

Tags: aerodynamics

I'm attempting to implement Theodorsen's lift deficiency function for an airfoil experiencing a harmonic variation in angle of attack due to an oscillating freestream (i.e., not pitch oscillations).  Following Leishman's *Helicopter Aerodynamics* I have an expression for this (as follows), but I'm unsure how to implement it.

$C_l=2\pi\left[C(k)+i\frac{\omega b}{2v_\infty}\right]\bar{\alpha}e^{i\omega t}$

where $\omega$ is the circular frequency of the AoA oscillation, $\bar{\alpha}$ is the amplitude of the oscillation, $b$ is the semi-chord length, and $C(k)$ is Theodorsen's function, evaluated at a given reduced frequency.  I get my values for this from http://soliton.ae.gatech.edu/labs/windtunl/classes/unstaero/unstaf/theofn.html.  This expression is then plotted against angle of attack, given as $\alpha=\bar{\alpha}sin(\omega t)$.  Using Matlab to plot the real part of this expression, I get the following:

[image: My implementation of the Theodorsen approximation]

As shown, all I get is a rough circle.  I should be able to plot a hysteresis loop similar to this (from Leishman, *Principles of Helicopter Aerodynamics*, 2006): [image: Theodorsen prediction for flat plate airfoil undergoing pure angle of attack oscillations]

I realize that both plots are for different ranges of angle of attack, but the expression should produce similar results (in terms of trends, appearance) in either case.  Am I missing something on the implementation of this function, or in my understanding of what this function should do?

Comment: 1. Could you provide some more details about your implementation like the values for $\omega$, $k$ and the software you're using? I just tested it and get a hysteresis loop like the one in your question. 2. Did you derive the $C_l$ expression yourself? Isn't a $\pi$ missing ($C_l=2\pi\cdot [...]$)?

Comment: Ah, you're right.  I copied it incorrectly from the Leishman text I mentioned...editing.  As for the results: I'm using Matlab to plot the real part of the expression for a reduced frequency, k, of 0.1.  Since $k=\omega b/v_\infty$, I find $\omega$ to be 5 rad/s ($v_\infty=25$ ft/s, $b=0.5$ ft).  I use $\bar{\alpha}=8^\circ=0.140$ rad and plot over t=0,3, which should be about 2 periods.  How do you get your results?  I'll put up a plot of what I'm getting too.

Comment: The assumption to get the $C_l = ...$ formula is $\alpha(t) = \bar{\alpha}\cdot e^{i \omega t}$. The real part of the angle is $\alpha=\cos{\omega t}$, not the sine.  That should fix your plot. I'll try to post later an answer with some background for readers unfamiliar with Theodorsen.

Comment: Oh bother.  Yep, that's it.  Thanks!  I'll pick your answer as soon as it's up.